# Unable to sort array of dates pulled from innerText

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, sorting, date

I’m currently trying to pull dates from the DOM (formatted as `1563595200`) into an array in Javascript. The next step is to sort the array properly from closest date to farthest away and cannot figure it out.

Example of element: 
`<span class="meta-item date">1563595200</span>`

Javascript:

```
    var className = document.getElementsByClassName('date');
    var classnameCount = className.length;
    var IdStore = new Array();
    for(var j = 0; j < classnameCount; j++){
        var dateString = className[j].innerText;                
        IdStore.push(dateString);
    }
    console.log(IdStore);
    var IdStore = IdStore.sort(function(a,b){
  // Turn your strings into dates, and then subtract them
  // to get a value that is either negative, positive, or zero.
  return new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date);
});

    console.log(IdStore);
}
storeid();
```

I expect it to be sorted from nearest date to farthest away but the sorting function isn't doing anything.

Comment: The elements of your array are strings, they don't have a date property, so a.date and b.date don't exist.  You should try a and b instead.

Comment: Also, if those values are actually dates represented as number of (milli)seconds since an epoch, you could just sort them using `return parseInt(b) - parseInt(a);`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey—there's no need for *parseInt*, the `-` operator coerces the values to number anyway. Though for clarity it might be good to explicitly coerce the values to number and, perhaps, to deal with exceptions that result in NaN (though they will still sort just fine).

Comment: update: okay I misread the first suggestion. It's sorting properly now.

Answer (score -1):

You should not be re-declaring a variable here.  Remove the var keyword when you are assigning the sort function to IdStore

```
IdStore = IdStore.sort(function(a,b){
```

Comment: No need for either since sort() mutates original in place

Comment: Declaring the same variable twice with *var* has no ill–effects, it has no bearing on the OP's issue.

Comment: I realize this should have been a comment, but yes you are right for the `var` word specifically.  `const` and `let` will throw a syntax error.  Still not good practice